# Make method accept only parameter with particular annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have a method

```
public static void injectConfiguration(@Configurable Object bean) {}
```

And I have a class which holds field

```
public class LauncherComponentsHolder {
@Configurable
public RoomDao roomDao;
```

And I have main class, where I call that method and pass him that:

```
LauncherComponentsHolder root = new LauncherComponentsHolder();
root.roomDao = new RoomDaoImpl();
root.guestDao = new GuestDaoImpl();
root.maintenanceDao = new MaintenanceDaoImpl();
ConfigInjector.injectConfiguration(root.roomDao);
ConfigInjector.injectConfiguration(root.guestDao);
ConfigInjector.injectConfiguration(root.maintenanceDao);
```

**Problem is that the method accepts all the 3 parameters**, (no warnings, errors, nothing) however only roomDao is annotated. Annotation itself:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Configurable {

}
```

How to make the restriction, so that `injectConfiguration(@Configurable Object bean)` would accept only field (or class instance) annotated with `Configurable` ?

Comment: You can't. But you could create a [marker interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-marker-interfaces), which has the annotation, then have all allowed classes implant that interface, then change your method to accept the interface.

Comment: @Bohemian that is cumbersome)) I guessed to use interface, but also thought there is more elegant syntax construction using annotations. Saaaad))

Comment: There is another way that is more elegant to use but more complicated under the hood: Use aspect programming to intercept the call then use reflection to inspect the annotations declared on the class of the parameter and throw an exception if the parameter doesn't have the correct annotation. See [AspectJ](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using an annotation processor.
An example of such a tool is the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).
It enables you to write type annotations in your program, then it type-checks the type annotations at compile time.  It issues a warning if the type annotations in your program are not consistent with one another.

The easiest way for you to implement the checking would be to use the [Subtyping Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#subtyping-checker).

Here is an [example](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#subtyping-example) from its manual:

```java
import myPackage.qual.Encrypted;

...

public @Encrypted String encrypt(String text) {
    // ...
}

// Only send encrypted data!
public void sendOverInternet(@Encrypted String msg) {
    // ...
}

void sendText() {
    // ...
    @Encrypted String ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext);
    sendOverInternet(ciphertext);
    // ...
}

void sendPassword() {
    String password = getUserPassword();
    sendOverInternet(password);
}
```

When you invoke `javac` using a couple extra command-line arguments, `javac` issues an error for the second invocation of `sendOverInternet` but not the first one:

```
YourProgram.java:42: incompatible types.
found   : @PossiblyUnencrypted java.lang.String
required: @Encrypted java.lang.String
    sendOverInternet(password);
                     ^
```